# How to store a n*n matrix consisting of integers into a bitmask value?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have a `n*n` matrix, let us consider n as 3.

So there will be a total 9 elements. My Matrix can store Integers. When I change these integer values of the 9 elements, I will get some unique combinations of matrices.

Now i want to put these grids as key in a `Hash Map`.

An easy way to do this is to convert my matrix in some format(may be bits). So there will be encoding of this matrix, and then when i retrieve i must decode.

I read bit masks work well here. But I am unable to figure out how to create a bit mask out of a grid in java.

I am looking for a solution which tells me how to do it through an example, and the logic flow for encoding or decoding the grid to bit mask.

Comment: Instead of creating a bitmask, you could simply construct a string composed of the 9 integers, separated by, for instance, a space. Each matrix has its own string representation and a matrix can be reconstructed from that string.

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is whether the time and space to generate bitmask keys from your matrix is going to be more or less efficient than using a simpler hash (such as just adding up all the values in the matrix). Hash values do not need to be unique, they just need to be consistent.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I cannot add as I need those values again, and i will be manipulating them . Some other Hash Function might be good, and that's why i was looking into bit masks, as a viable option. I am not sure about the time aspect though and that's why I want to learn by trying it

Comment: @RobertKock That's a nice approach, but i think converting int to string and then manipulating them would take a lot more space and time. Also, I want to know how bitmasks works in my scenerio. I want to learn, but cant find a tutorial  for that

Comment: @GoPro honestly, you need to seriously rethink what you are trying to do. Mutable matrixes are going to be seriously flawed as HashMap keys, and why you need to serialize your matrix to a bitmask in the first place.

Comment: Have these integers a maximum values? In other words, how many bits will each of them occupy? If, for instance, all values are below 256, you could set the value on index (0, 0) in the first 8 bits, the value on (0, 1) in the bits from 8 to 15, etc.

Comment: You might have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html. Let each integer within your matrix occupy a specific range of bits (0-31 for the first; 32-63 for the second, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, i am looking into oracle docs now!